# Can I replace storage engine of MongoDB as a Key-Value store

Tags: mongodb, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

MongoDB is easy to start, but it is not easy to ensure availability (buy EC2 to build a master-slave? or more replica set ?). And there is many key-value public service(Dynamo, AzureTable) with high availability and good performance. So if I can replace MongoDB storage engine with, such as Dynamo, then I got friendly MongoDB API and high available storage. Is that possible ?

Comment: Is it available? Not yet. Part of the work done with the release of MongoDB 3.0 was to make storage engines "pluggable" in order to support the new WiredTiger storage engine. In "theory" then any "adapter" to another solution could be plugged in and used as an alternate engine in confiuration. Is this all the way there yet? Not really. And as such no other pluggable engines are availble right now.

Comment: @BlakesSeven While there is no dedicated engine for Key/Value stores available, it is easy to configure and use MongoDB in that scenario with even some variety. See my answer below.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Why do you seem to think you are informing me of something? That is not what the OP asked specifically, and neither is it a programming topic.

Comment: @BlakesSeven you seemed to have missed that possibility and I just wanted to let you know. And with a bit of thinking sideways, the question is close enough for me to data modeling ;) Please excuse me if harm was done.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I don't miss much of anything. Not the question that was aked, therefore I did not respond that way.

Comment: @Blakes Seven, that is right, "In theory, that is possible". I just want to if any one thinking about this like me, so we can do an discussion about the tech detail.

Comment: @Raymond Beforte your "point" which I understood came under an attempted "hijack", what I was generally "inferring" there is that the "pluggable" concept is a work in "active" progress. The particular "nod" here I can give is towards "HDFS" and others around that vein, where there is noted interest ( WiredTIger / SleepyCat if you did not see the connection ) into "use case" storage engines below a logical layer such as MongoDB. Yout question is acutally worthy of a definitive answer, but what you are really asking does not exist at present. Hopefully in the future it will.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is pretty easy to use MongoDB as an in memory key value store:

### Approach 1: Prevent disk usage

1. [Disable journaling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.journal.enabled)
2. [Set `syncPeriodSecs` to 0](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.syncPeriodSecs)
3. Store the key in the `_id` field and the value in a `value` field.
4. Now you have an all in-memory key/value store

The problem with this approach is that you are limited to your machines RAM size and your data does not persist.

A by far more elegant approach is to use

### Approach 2: Using covered queries

A covered query is a query which is answered by using only an index, which is kept in memory as long as enough is available. If the index exceeds the RAM, the least recently used parts are "swapped" to disk. Furthermore, your key/value pairs are persisted. And all that happens transparently.

1. Create an index over both the keys and the values:

   ```js
   db.keyValueCollection.createIndex({_id:1,value:1})
   ```
2. Make sure MongoDB is informed that only `_id` and `value` are needed and it doesn't need to bother reading anything else from disk (flexible schema!) using projection to limit the fields returned in your query to those two fields:

   ```js
   db.keyValueCollection.find({_id:"foo"},{_id:1,value:1})
   ```
3. Done! Your queries will now be answered from RAM, overflow will be automatically handled and your values will persist.

### Side note

Ensuring availability with MongoDB is close to foolproof. Choose a replica set name, add it to all confit files, fire up one of the members, initiate the replica set and add the members. Problem solved.

*Edit*: removed an artificial `key` field, and made sure the query in approach 2 is covered by limiting the fields returned.

Comment: My question is not use MongoDB as a key-value store, but replace existing MongoDB storage engine with popular key-value storage. Any way, thanks.

Comment: @Raymond got your question wrong then. Still, I don't get the point.